# troubles threads in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I need to calculate sum of elements in the textbox and number of elements at the same time. So I decided to create two threads - one for length of the number, and one for sum of elements. But when I start only one thread - it works correct. But when I start the second thread - form begins to work slow or stops working at all.
I create two threads

```
thrd = new Thread(GetLength);
thrd.Start();
thrd1 = new Thread(SetSum);
thrd1.Start();
```

And these are threads' functions for calculation length of the number in textbox and for calculation sum of its elements.

```
private void SetSum()
{
    while (true)
    {
       if (this.label3.InvokeRequired)
           this.Invoke(new Action(() => label3.Text = this.GetSum().ToString()));
    }
}

private int GetSum()
{
    string n = textBox1.Text;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
     {
            try
            {
                sum += int.Parse(n[i].ToString());
            }
            catch (FormatException) { };
        }
        return sum;
     }

private void GetLength()
{
    while (true)
     {
            if (this.label2.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = " |  Length = " + textBox1.Text.Length.ToString()));
     }
}
```

Where is the problem? Synchronization?

I have found a solution - I add `Thread.Sleep(1)` in while loop in GetLength method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here.

1. The task at hand is much too small for a (full) Thread. Threads are expensive to create.
2. By Invoking the main action, all work is done on the Main thread. Your solution is not multi-threaded after all.
3. Counting is easily done as a by-product of Summing (or vice versa) so 2 threads/tasks is overkill.
4. The `while(true) ...` loop will drag your process down, consuming too much CPU time for nothing

The simple answer here is not to use any threads, just run some logic in `textBox1.TextChanged`.

Comment: But there is no other solution besides threads for infinite loop. Or it will not move to any other operations with form.

Comment: Yes there is: No Threads. If the goal is to update a label when the contents of a TextBox changes, the TextChanged event is all you need. Your threading approach has too much errors to repair in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in fact synchronization: there's too much of it.

You're spawning threads that only do `Invoke`s, which means the UI thread is doing all the work.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is an infinite loop without any Thread.Sleep or any other Wait. This will bring CPU to 100%. You should tie this to some event or any other activity which will trigger GetLength

```
private void GetLength() 
{ 
    while (true) 
     { 
            if (this.label2.InvokeRequired) 
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = " |  Length = " + textBox1.Text.Length.ToString())); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: I write in textbox and it calculates its length - I don't know how to change it.(the same for a sum)